# Problema al utilizar 2 javascript API de google maps en un mismo index.html

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-v3, apigoogle

Estoy queriendo cargar 2 mapas con la aplicación de google en un mismo index.html. Los mapas al probarlos uno por uno no tengo problema, ambos se cargan y funcionan correctamente.

El primer mapa muestra la ubicación del usuario en un `<div id="map">` de la siguiente manera:

`mapa 1`

```js
var map, infoWindow;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,


    styles: [{
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "weight": 1.5
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": 40
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 25
          },
          {
            "visibility": "simplified"
          },
          {
            "weight": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.attraction",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#5485c0"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "on"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#5485c0"
          },
          {
            "saturation": 40
          },
          {
            "lightness": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        }]
      }
    ]
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: {
          lat: pos.lat,
          lng: pos.lng
        },
        title: 'Hey! Estas aquí'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=AIzaSyBhSrbK0MeReqvKKFaK1umUYL_LDGSYBwg&callback=initMap">
  </script>
  
</body>
```

La segunda función carga un GMAP de la API de javascript en un `<div id='map2'>` que tiene la cualidad de poder arrastrar el `marker` y guarda las coordenadas en un `<input type="text" id='coords'>`

`mapa 2`

```js
var marker;          //variable del marcador
var coords = {};    //coordenadas obtenidas con la geolocalización

 

//Funcion principal
initCoords = function () 
{

    //usamos la API para geolocalizar el usuario
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function (position){
            coords =  {
              lng: position.coords.longitude,
              lat: position.coords.latitude
            };
            setMapa(coords);  //pasamos las coordenadas al metodo para crear el mapa
            
           
          },function(error){console.log(error);});
    
}



function setMapa (coords)
{   
      //Se crea una nueva instancia del objeto mapa
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'),
      {
        zoom: 13,
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng),

      });

      //Creamos el marcador en el mapa con sus propiedades
      //para nuestro obetivo tenemos que poner el atributo draggable en true
      //position pondremos las mismas coordenas que obtuvimos en la geolocalización
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng),

      });
      //agregamos un evento al marcador junto con la funcion callback al igual que el evento dragend que indica 
      //cuando el usuario a soltado el marcador
      marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
      
      marker.addListener( 'dragend', function (event)
      {
        //escribimos las coordenadas de la posicion actual del marcador dentro del input #coords
        document.getElementById("coords").value = this.getPosition().lat()+","+ this.getPosition().lng();
      });
}

//callback al hacer clic en el marcador lo que hace es quitar y poner la animacion BOUNCE
function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}

      function abrirGmap {
      $('#modalGmap').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){

          initCoords();
          console.log("si");
      })
    }
```

```css
html, body {

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding:0;
margin: 0;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<!-- comienzo del input id='coords' -->

<input id="coords" type="text" class="form-control" value="Ubicación" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGmap"/>

<!-- Comienzo del modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modalGmap" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document" style="width: 60%; height: 60%;">
              <div id="map2" class="modal-content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>

                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhSrbK0MeReqvKKFaK1umUYL_LDGSYBwg">
    </script>
 </body>
```

El problema parece ser que al cargar la clave de la API de google esta hace un callback=Function() osea llama directamente a la función cuando se carga, haciendo referencia a una sola de las dos funciones.

cosas que intenté:

probé borrar el callback=initMap y llamar a la función cuando el usuario hace clic en el `<input id="coords">` pero cuando hago esto solo funciona el mapa 2 y el primero deja de funcionar.

probé borrar ambas funciones Javascript del index.html y separarlas en 2 archivos javascript distintos y en el index.html crear una función del tipo

```html
Function initMaps {
    
    window.onload = function initMap();
    window.onload = function initCorrds();
  
}

 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhSrbK0MeReqvKKFaK1umUYL_LDGSYBwg">
  </script>
```

Pensaba que con esto al llamar a los archivos`mapa1.js` y `mapa2.js` entre `<head></head>` cuando llegara al script y al web terminara de cargar las funciones se iniciarían... pero no funcionó.

también probé con la etiqueta `onclick=function()` y `onload=function()` en los respectivos divs donde deben cargarse los mapas... pero no funcionó.

Bueno eso a sido mas o menos todo. espero alguien pueda ayudarme a resolver!

Muchas gracias

**PRUEBAS NUEVAS AL 17/12/2018**

En base a la respuesta de un usuario intenté separar ambas funciones en 2 archivos diferentes `gmap.js` y `GPSservice.js`. Luego en `index.html` llamo a ambos archivos entre `<head></head> con <script src js/gmap.js`etc. Luego antes de finalizar el `</body>` y debajo del script de la API de google cree la siguiente función

```
<script>
    function abrirGmap {

        initMap();
        initCoords();
    }

    window.onload = abrirGmap;

</script>
```

Esperaba que con esta función luego de cargar los archivos en el head y "encapsular" ambas funciones en una "función gatillo" que se cargaría mediante `window.onload = abrirGmap;`. El resultado: No funcionó.

El siguiente intento fue eliminar el `window.onload = abrirGmap;` de la función gatillo y agregar al script de la API de google un `callback=abrirGmap`. de la siguiente manera.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=AIzaSyBhSrbK0MeReqvKKFaK1umUYL_LDGSYBwg&callback=abrirGmap">
```

el resultado: no funcionó.

**SOLUCIÓN FINAL**

Separé ambas funciones ena rchivos distintos como se menciona mas arriba. a continuación los llamo en el head del `index.html` como se menciona arriba y al final antes del body encapsulo las funciones y ejecuto de la siguiente manera.

```
<script>

    function abrirGmap() {

        initMap();
        initCoords();
    }

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhSrbK0MeReqvKKFaK1umUYL_LDGSYBwg&callback=abrirGmap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios problems

**Primero:** Si quieres rendererizar dos mapas en la misma página no necesitas en absoluto llamar dos veces al script del API. Una vez basta. Dos veces te va a generar comportamientos inesperados como mínimo. Tampoco necesitas cargar dos veces jQuery.

**Segundo** Tu primer llamado al API está pasando como parámetro la función que se va a ejecutar *cuando termine de cargar el script del API* lo cual no tiene en absoluto relación con el momento en que termine de cargar el DOM. Por tanto no sacas nada tratando de meter ese comportamiento en `window.onload`.

**Tercero** Aunque tuviera sentido homologar la carga del script del API google maps a `window.onload`, cuando pones:

```
window.onload = function initMap();
window.onload = function initCorrds();
```

La segunda declaración pisa la primera. Y eso sin contar que sintácticamente eso no significa nada. Para invocar a una función no le antepones `function`.

**Cuarto:**

Si te olvidas por completo del evento `window.onload` y te limitas a definir una función que gatilla a las otras dos (y usas la siguiente sintaxis corregida)

```
function initMaps() {
   initMap();
   initCoords();
}
```

Necesitas que alguien o algo la invoque, de manera que sería momento de volver a añadir tu callback en el llamado al API (**que es el único llamado que haces, olvídate de hacer 2**):

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMaps&key=AIzaSyBhSrbK0MeReqvKKFaK1umUYL_LDGSYBwg">
```

Además yo cambiaría el nombre de `initMaps` porque se ve muy parecido a `initMap`. Mejor le pondría `initDosMapas` o algo muy evidente.

**Quinto (este no es un problema bloqueante)**

Estás declarando una variable global `map`  al inicio de tu script.

```
var map, infoWindow;

function initMap() { ... }
```

Y luego haces `shadowing` de ésta en tu segundo mapa:

```
function setMapa (coords)
{   
  //Se crea una nueva instancia del objeto mapa
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'),
  {
    zoom: 13,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng),

  });

 ...
}
```

Al hacer eso la referencia a la variable se pierde en algunos ámbitos, y eso te puede llevar a confusiones.

Comment: gracias por responder. Al leer tu respuesta intente hacer lo siguiente. Separe las 2 funciones correspondientes a cada mapa en 2 archivos distintos a los que he llamado gmap.js y GPSservice.js. Desde index.html llamo a ambos archivos con src entre head y /head. Al final del body hice lo siguiente.  `<script>
   function abrirGmap {

    initMap();
    initCoords();
   }

   window.onload = abrirGmap;

    </script>` y el script de la API quedó sin el callback. Como esto no funciono. probe eliminar el `window.onload` y agregue al script callback=abrirGmap. pero no funciono tampoco.

Comment: Amigo pude resolverlo! al final lo que me faltaba era que en la función `<script> function abrirGmap { initMap(); initCoords(); } window.onload = abrirGmap; </script>` falta los () luego de function abrirGmap.. quedó de la siguiente manera `<script> function abrirGmap() { initMap(); initCoords(); }</script>`  luego la llamo en el script del API con callback=abrirGmap y funciona! muchas gracias

Comment: vale, pero quita cualquier referencia a window.onload. El ciclo de vida de la ventana no condiciona el momento en que google maps api termine de cargar, máxime si lo pones como asíncrono y diferido

Comment: Si, es lo que he hecho. Borre el window.onload y traslade la carga de la funcion al script de google con el callback=abrirGmap. En el futuro evitare usar el window.onload y en su defecto usare document.ready o por el estilo.muchas gracias